# Extract properly to a vector

Tags: c++

I have made a program that reads from a text file, adds components to a structure and adds every structure element to a vector. The problem is that for some reason, the reading function seems not to work at all.

Here is the code:

```
struct address
{
    string street;
    int zip;
    string city;
};

struct person
{
    string name;
    string id;
    address location;
};

istream & operator >>(istream & in, person & p)
{
    getline(in, p.name);
    getline(in, p.id);
    getline(in, p.location.street);

    return in;
}

void read_file(string filename)
{
    vector<person> persons;
    ifstream input;
    input.open(filename);

    if (!input.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File Not Found" << endl;
    }

    person temp;
    input >> temp;
    persons.push_back(temp);
    input.close();

    if (persons.size() == 0)
    {
        cout << "The are no contacts" << endl;
    }
    else cout << "There are" << " " << persons.size() << " " << "contacts in the file" << endl;
}
```

The lines in the text file look like this:

```
Test Name Surname
Id 1234567890
Adress, postcode, city
```

When I say it does not work I mean the read function does not show if there are elements in the vector.

Here is the text file: [names.txt](http://www.filedropper.com/names)

Main code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

const string filename = "C://Users/TEMP/Desktop/lab1/names.txt";
int userinput = 0;


while (true)
{


    cout << "Menu: \n1) Sök del av  personnamn\n2) Sök stader\n3) Exit" <<  endl;

    cin >> userinput;
    cout << endl;

    if (userinput == 1)
    {
        namnsok;
    }
        else if (userinput == 2)
        {
            stadsok;
        }
            else if (userinput == 3)
            {
                break;
            }
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide few lines of the input file and a more precise problem than "do not work"

Comment: Seems to work well on my machine. Please provide input file.

Comment: @AdiLevin i am not getting any compilation error but it does not show if there are elements or not.

Comment: So, you're not reaching the `cout` statement in the end of the program. This means that an exception was thrown. This can be a result of bad data in the input file. If you share it, maybe we can help.

Comment: is this ALL of the code... are you just missing a main() function?

Answer (score -1):

I had to change the line
`input.open(filename);`
to `input.open(filename.c_str(),ifstream::in);` to get it to work for me. You will only read the first person from the input though.

Comment: 'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleApplication1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. That's all i am getting!!!